# Unable to pass string parameter to a simple Javascript function being invoked when a hyperlink is clicked

Tags: javascript

It's a very simple question but I couldn't figure it out. I'm trying to pass parameters to a Javascript function which is invoked when a hyper link is clicked.

It works just fine when the parameters are number but doesn't work when one of them is of type string. I even tried to escape them but unfortunately to no avail.

The following is a very simple code.

```
function temp(a, b)
{
    alert(a+ "   "+b);
}

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="temp(x, 2);">Click</a>
```

It doesn't work complaining `x is undefined` `x` is here `onclick="temp(x, 2);"`. When I modify the function something like this `temp(1,2);`, it works and alerts as specified.

What might be the reason? What is the solution?

Comment: you x is a variable assignment... use `'x'` to pass it as string

Comment: That I also tried but unfortunately no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should avoid passing an undefined variable... `x` is only a variable as a string starts and end with double or single quotes

```
function temp(a, b) {
    alert(a+ "   "+b);
}

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="temp('x', 2);">Click</a>
```

I also created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UJmWc/) to show it works

EDIT: this revision of the fiddle shows that you can also switch the quotes used in the markup... if you are used to double quotes for JS strings [fiddle revision 1](http://jsfiddle.net/UJmWc/1/)

Comment: I had to do something like this to make it work in my actual application in JSP `onclick=\"selectOrderStatus('"+od_status+"', "+order_id+";);\"`. Even this one `onclick='selectOrderStatus('"+od_status+"', "+order_id+");'` enclosed within single quotes doesn't work.

Comment: Not even this one were working `onclick='selectOrderStatus('\"+od_status+\"', \"+order_id+\");'`. Therefore, I needed to post the question here. Thanks.

Comment: a you should mention in the question that the code is generated via PHP and a small piece of this php code would have also helped :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="temp('x', 2);">Click</a>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ky3Wq/)

With your code, you treat `x` as it was a variable, while it wasn't decalred, surrond it with quotes.

---

If you want to use the `x` variable, declare it about the `<a>`:

```
<script>
    var x ="foo";

    function temp(a, b) {
        alert(a + "   " + b);
    }​
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="temp(x, 2);">Click</a>
```